# Macros compilation errors in cpp (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros

```
#include <iostream>
#define hello()(printf("Hello");)

using namespace std;

void main()
{
hello();
}
```

i am using the following code which gives a compilation error !!
what could be possibly wrong in this program !!

Comment: `main` is required to return an `int`. And what's the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses can't be used to enclose statements.  What you want is:

```
#define hello() printf("Hello");
```

The semicolon is also unnecessary, or maybe you meant:

```
#define hello() { printf("Hello"); }
```

Aside from that syntax error, you should probably include `cstdio` to use `printf`, and `main` should return `int`.